# Display TinyMCE editor to textareas after Jquery .load onclick

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce

I am trying to add a TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor to my textareas.

I have a table with a `td` that the user can click to `.load` a form with input fields, labels, textareas etc.

My `td` looks like this:

```
<a href="#" id="display_info" onclick="displayFacilityInformation(61)">Something</a>
```

`displayFacilityInformation()` looks like this:

```
function displayFacilityInformation (facID){
    $("#facility_details").load("facilitydetails.php?q="+facID);
    $('#facility_details_wrapper').show();
    $("#newaccount_form, #newuser_form, #newfacility_form, #accounts, #facilities, #new_section_form").hide(); //hide other divs

    //tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor',true, general_facility_info); //gave me console error "general_facility_info is undefined")

    //tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, 'general_facility_info');

    //tinymce.init({
        //selector: "textarea"
    //});

    //tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, 'body');
};
```

The various things I have tried are commented out. (`general_facility_info` is the ID of one of the textareas)

`facilitydetails.php` outputs an HTML form to a `div id="facility_details"` which has my textarea that I wish to become a tinyMCE editor.

My console is not throwing any errors and I am able to create other textareas that are tinymce editors in other (hidden) forms.

Does it have something to do with adding in elements with Jquery `.load`?

How can I make the newly added textarea's tinyMCE editors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading this data asynchronously. You need to run the init method as a callback for when the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function is done running, otherwise it runs before the textareas have potentially loaded and nothing happens.

See the docs I linked to, where the 3rd optional param is:

> complete
>   Type: Function( String responseText, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>   A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

So your method should look more like:

```
function displayFacilityInformation (facID){
    $("#facility_details").load("facilitydetails.php?q="+facID, function() {
        $('#facility_details_wrapper').show();
        $("#newaccount_form, #newuser_form, #newfacility_form, #accounts, #facilities, #new_section_form").hide(); //hide other divs

        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea"
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly my problem. TIL callbacks, thanks so much this will help me with a few other things as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean

Comment: It sounds like you're resetting the textareas? Are you running tinyMCE functions in the click methods?